# How do I spawn the colour picker from a browser on Linux?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, colors, opera

when browsing the [HTML Color Picker](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp), I clicked on a button labelled as "Or Use HTML5:" which spawns a GTK3 colour picker for browsers.

### The Firefox Colour Picker:

[image]

On Chromium and Opera (and probably on chromium based browsers) however, the Colour Picker looks a bit different.

### Chromium Colour Picker:

[image]

### On Falkon Browser:

[image]

I am interested in learning how to spawn the colour pickers so that I can use without going to the particular website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With html:

`<input type=color onchange="document.body.style.backgroundColor=value">`